# How can I compare two ordered lists in python?

Tags: python, list, equality

I have two lists:

```
a = [0,2,1]
b = [0,2,1]
```

How can I compare these two lists to see if they are both equal/identical, with the constraint that they have to be in the **same** order?

I have seen questions asking to compare two lists by sorting them, but in my specific case, I am not checking for a sorted comparison, but **identical** list comparison.

Answer (score 258, accepted):

Just use the classic `==` operator:

```
>>> [0,1,2] == [0,1,2]
True
>>> [0,1,2] == [0,2,1]
False
>>> [0,1] == [0,1,2]
False
```

Lists are equal if elements at the same index are equal. Ordering is taken into account then.

Comment: This can return the following error with a numpy list: `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: What @AlexReynolds said. You have to test with `all(arr1 == arr2)` or `(arr1 == arr2).all()`.

Comment: @Alex That's an array, not a list. They're both ordered data types, but conceptually different. An action you apply to an array is applied to all of its elements, but the same isn't true for lists.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to just check if they are identical or not, `a == b` should give you true / false with ordering taken into account.

In case you want to compare elements, you can use numpy for comparison

`c = (numpy.array(a) == numpy.array(b))`

Here, c will contain an array with 3 elements all of which are true (for your example). In the event elements of a and b don't match, then the corresponding elements in c will be false.

Comment: And then check whether c.all() is True

Answer (score 6):

The expression `a == b` should do the job.