# I have a list of tuples containing dictionaries. How do I edit my code to find the values in a separate list, inside these dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a data structure L = [(int, dict{key: values}), (int,dict{key: values})...].

Given an input list [0,1] I want to find ***any*** dictionary key where both/all values of the input list [0,1] exist.

Currently, my bug is that if I use input_list = [0,1], the function will return a match where the dictionary values are just [0] and where values are [0,1]. Only this second result is desirable. I feel like this is a minute change, but I can't grasp it. What do I change to make this happen?

**Code**

```
#Python3
L = [(0, {0: [0], 1: [0, 1], 2: [0, 2], 3: [0, 3], 4: [0, 4]}), (1, {0: [1, 0], 1: [1], 2: [5, 1, 2,], 3: [1, 3], 4: [1, 4]}), (2, {0: [2, 0], 1: [2, 1], 2: [2], 3: [2, 3], 4: [2, 4]}), (3, {0: [3, 0], 1: [3, 1], 2: [3, 2], 3: [3], 4: [3, 4]}), (4, {0: [4, 0], 1: [4, 1], 2: [4, 2], 3: [4, 3], 4: [4]})]

#input_list = (eval(input('Enter your list: ')))
#input_list = ([0,1])
print('Input: ' + str(input_list))
for tupl in L:
    dict_a = (tupl[1])
    matching_key = ([key for key, value in dict_a.items() if all(v in input_list for v in value)])
    print('Node: ' + str(tupl[0]) + ' Match at key(s): ' + str(matching_key))
```

**Output**

```
L = [(0, {0: [0], 1: [0, 1], 2: [0, 2], 3: [0, 3], 4: [0, 4]}), (1, {0: [1, 0], 1: [1], 2: [5, 1, 2,], 3: [1, 3], 4: [1, 4]}), (2, {0: [2, 0], 1: [2, 1], 2: [2], 3: [2, 3], 4: [2, 4]}), (3, {0: [3, 0], 1: [3, 1], 2: [3, 2], 3: [3], 4: [3, 4]}), (4, {0: [4, 0], 1: [4, 1], 2: [4, 2], 3: [4, 3], 4: [4]})]

Enter your list: [0,1]
Input: [0, 1]
Node: 0 Match at key(s): [0, 1]
Node: 1 Match at key(s): [0, 1]
Node: 2 Match at key(s): []
Node: 3 Match at key(s): []
Node: 4 Match at key(s): []

Enter your list: [1,5,2]
Input: [1, 5, 2]
Node: 0 Match at key(s): []
Node: 1 Match at key(s): [1, 2]
Node: 2 Match at key(s): [1, 2]
Node: 3 Match at key(s): []
Node: 4 Match at key(s): []
```

Thank you:)

Comment: Do you actually want ```input_list == value```?  Or if ```value``` contains all items in ```input_list```?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the code checking if `value` contains all the items in `input_list` the wrong way around. `all(v in input_list for v in value)` checks that all the items in `value` can be found from `input_list`. If you change it the other way around it will work as you expected:

```
all(v in value for v in input_list)
```

Note that if you would convert `input_list` to [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) you could easily check if `input_list` is a subset of `value`. That would be easier to understand and more efficient:

```
L = [(0, {0: [0], 1: [0, 1], 2: [0, 2], 3: [0, 3], 4: [0, 4]}), (1, {0: [1, 0], 1: [1], 2: [5, 1, 2,], 3: [1, 3], 4: [1, 4]}), (2, {0: [2, 0], 1: [2, 1], 2: [2], 3: [2, 3], 4: [2, 4]}), (3, {0: [3, 0], 1: [3, 1], 2: [3, 2], 3: [3], 4: [3, 4]}), (4, {0: [4, 0], 1: [4, 1], 2: [4, 2], 3: [4, 3], 4: [4]})]

input_list = set([0,1])

for tupl in L:
    dict_a = tupl[1]
    matching_key = [key for key, value in dict_a.items() if input_list <= set(value)]
    print('Node: ' + str(tupl[0]) + ' Match at key(s): ' + str(matching_key))
```

Output:

```
Node: 0 Match at key(s): [1]
Node: 1 Match at key(s): [0]
Node: 2 Match at key(s): []
Node: 3 Match at key(s): []
Node: 4 Match at key(s): []
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. I see what you did, good lesson

Answer (score 0):

You can use set subtraction to solve:

```
#Python3
L = [(0, {0: [0], 1: [0, 1], 2: [0, 2], 3: [0, 3], 4: [0, 4]}), (1, {0: [1, 0], 1: [1], 2: [5, 1, 2,], 3: [1, 3], 4: [1, 4]}), (2, {0: [2, 0], 1: [2, 1], 2: [2], 3: [2, 3], 4: [2, 4]}), (3, {0: [3, 0], 1: [3, 1], 2: [3, 2], 3: [3], 4: [3, 4]}), (4, {0: [4, 0], 1: [4, 1], 2: [4, 2], 3: [4, 3], 4: [4]})]

input_list = (eval(input('Enter your list: ')))
#input_list = [1,5,2]
print('Input: ' + str(input_list))
for tupl in L:
    dict_a = (tupl[1])
    matching_key = []
    for key, lst in tupl[1].items():
        if not (set(lst) - set(input_list)):
            matching_key.append(key)
    print('Node: ' + str(tupl[0]) + ' Match at key(s): ' + str(matching_key))
```

And I would recommend you to avoid constructions like this `[key for key, value in dict_a.items() if all(v in input_list for v in value)]` because it confuses, it makes your code hard to understand.

Comment: How would you edit this to improve readability, and keep it efficient? (in reference to niemmi's sollution)

Comment: I think Niemmi's solution is pretty good. Sometimes it's better to avoid expressions like `[key for key, value in dict_a.items() if input_list <= set(value)]`. They are readable though but also they may confuse especially if you want to make some changes in your scipt. The other disadvantage is if you have an error in a line like `[key for key, value in dict_a.items() if input_list <= set(value)]` you don't know exactly which operation led to the exception. But if you do as I showed, the traceback will show you the exact line with the error.

Answer (score -1):

Please read:

[Check if two unordered lists are equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623114/check-if-two-unordered-lists-are-equal)
and [How can I compare two ordered lists in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36420022/how-can-i-compare-two-ordered-lists-in-python)

Depending on the semantics you want to use when checking for equality you can use one solution or the other. If you are going for a simple ordered list comparison, I would go with:

```
for tupl in L:
    dict_a = (tupl[1])
    if dict_a != input_list:
        continue
    print('Node: ' + str(tupl[0]) + ' Match at key(s): ' + str(matching_key))
```

Comment: ```dict_a``` is a dictionary, when would it be equal to a list?

Comment: oops, my bad. Then we would go back to:

Comment: oops again, we would go back to:
    for tupl in L:
        dict_a = (tupl[1])
        matching_key = ([key for key, value in dict_a.items() if v == iinput_list ])
        print('Node: ' + str(tupl[0]) + ' Match at key(s): ' + str(matching_key))