# Are all lists in a list equal

Tags: python

Is there a preferred general solution for testing equality of a list of lists. I'm attempting the apply this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36420022/how-can-i-compare-two-ordered-lists-in-python/36420107) more generally to a list of lists. I currently have the following solution, where `_list` is a generic list of unknown length/number of elements.

```
all(x == y for x, y in zip(_list, _list[1:]))
```

or if the order doesn't matter.

```
all([sorted(x) == sorted(y) for x, y in zip(_list, _list[1:])])
```

Beyond checking neighbouring lists for equality, how can/should this approach my improved?

Comment: I believe you can skip the list creation and just do `all(x == y for x, y in zip(_list, _list[1:]))`

Comment: Note that you do not have to compare each element with each other. You only need to check whether any, say the first, equals all others.

Comment: Your question suggests you want to compare two different lists of lists, but your code compares one list of lists to itself. Which is it?

Comment: Moreover, slicing will copy the tail of the list which is unecessarily costly.

Comment: You can hash the content of every list to a string, you will end up with a list of strings, then  check `len(set(list_of_strings)) == 1`

Comment: one *terrible* way to do this is use [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe, simple and fast enough way would be

```
all(a[0] == ax for ax in a)
```

You don't need to compare all elements pairwise, short route is to compare 1 vs all others. And in reality, better to compare against all (`ax in a`) instead of "against others" (`ax in a[1:]`), as slicing is most probably more computation-intensive that single comparison. Depends on your data, tho, but in general I'd suggest not bothering.

Answer (score -2):

use sorted build in function: for example if you have two list x and y then compare like:
 sorted(x)==sorted(y)

```
list1 = [7,9,8]
list2 = [8,7,9]
sorted(list1)==sorted(list2)
```