# What happens when IF statement is called on a list object? What method is called to determine whether is True or False?

Tags: python

When an IF statement is called on an instance of a list object, is there a magic method that is used to evaluate whether True or False is returned? For example,

```py
a = []
b = [1, 2, 3]

if a == b:  #  <---- __eq__() is called and returns False
    pass

if a:       #  <---- what is called here that returns False?
    pass
```

Is it: 
a.__bool__ (a.__nonzero__)? 
a.__len__?

or something else completely?

Comment: The document says both `__bool__()` and `__len__()` are used https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Comment: @ymonad, make this an answer to this question please!!!! This is the best answer!  I'd post it, but I don't want to take credit.

Comment: Since other stackoverflower's are posting good answers. so just vote or approve them.

Comment: But yours is better.  The one upvoted is misleading, since it implies that \__nonzero__ has anything to do with this particular case, which it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks @ymonad! The doc answered the question.

Comment: I kinda/sorta already knew the answer to this, but it was good to get a refresh by reading that documentation.  Looking at it, I noticed something interesting that I'm now going to try hard to remember, as I could see it being important in some cases: **(Important exception: the Boolean operations or and and always return one of their operands.)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ymonad gives the best answer in the question's comments, by simply referring to this doc:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

I don't want credit for this.  I just can't handle it when the best answer isn't even an answer.  If one can simply point to documentation, that will just about always be the best answer.

...grrrr...hey @ymonad, can I pass you a bounty or something, lol?

Answer (score 2):

Experiment time!

```
class Falsy:
    def __nonzero__(self):
        print("it's __nonzero__")
        return False
    def __len__(self):
        print("it's __len__")
        return 0
    def __bool__(self):
        print("it's __bool__")
        return False
    def __eq__(self, other):
        print("it's __eq__")
        return False

if Falsy():
    pass

# => it's __bool__
```

You can experiment with removing the methods to confirm which priority they are tested in (`__bool__`, then `__len__`, for Python 3).

Comment: This would be a useful answer if you also showed the list’s `__dict__` so you can see which methods exist.

Comment: How about showing this actually applied to the question, including the output you'd get?

Comment: @Steve: The output is included.

Comment: @Amadan, I see what you're doing now.  Sorry.  I misread what you were doing, and the commented output threw me off.  Thought that was part of the code.  I took off my -1.  I don't think this really answers the question though, as the question involved what methods exist and get called on an empty array.  Falsy is not an empty array.  An empty array won't have a \__bool__ method.  It WILL have a \__len__ method, which is what in the end determines why it is considered "False", because its length is 0.

Comment: @Amadan, what your answer shows, which is cool, is which method is called first in the case where an object has all of the possible methods that could determine True/Falseness. - \__bool__ wins!  You've shown that.  But again, an empty array won't have a \__bool__ method.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation [https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.**nonzero**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__):

`object.__nonzero__(self)`

Called to implement truth value testing and the built-in operation `bool()`; should return `False` or `True`, or their integer equivalents `0` or `1`. When this method is not defined, `__len__()` is called, if it is defined, and the object is considered true if its result is nonzero. If a class defines neither `__len__()` nor `__nonzero__()`, all its instances are considered true.

And for Python 3 [https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.**nonzero**](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__):

`object.__bool__(self)`

Called to implement truth value testing and the built-in operation `bool()`; should return `False` or `True`. When this method is not defined, `__len__()` is called, if it is defined, and the object is considered true if its result is nonzero. If a class defines neither `__len__()` nor `__bool__()`, all its instances are considered true.

Try:

```
class MyList(list):
    def __bool__(self):
        return True


print(bool(list([])))
if list([]):
    print('This does not print')


print(bool(MyList([])))
if MyList([]):
    print('This prints')
```

Comment: This answer contains the truth, but it really has nothing to do with \__bool__ in this case, so it's more complicated than it needs to be.  @ymonad gives the best answer in the question's comments, by simply referring to this doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Answer (score 0):

Consulting the C-Python API documentation for PyList ...

https://docs.python.org/3.7/c-api/list.html

... we can see there is no list-specific “as bool” function.  The only thing which can return the “truth” value is `PyList_Size(PyObject *list)`, so the answer must be `a.__len__()` is used.

Disclaimer: At least, for CPython.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36420022/how-can-i-compare-two-ordered-lists-in-python/36420107).

I am not sure what you mean. If I assume you are looking for a Java's .equals() equivalent, I am going to say, there is no such thing in python.

An empty list is always False in python.