# how variable == value in python

Tags: python, object, variables

In `a = [1, 2]` and `b = [1, 2]`, `a == b` is **True** and `a is b` is **False** but could someone please explain how `a == [1, 2]` returns **True**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a difference between "==" and "is"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is)

Comment: [Lists are equal if elements at the same index are equal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36420107/5168011)

Comment: Try the printing the ```id``` of both the variables. You will get your answer for ```is``` and ```==``` only checks the elements in the list

Comment: @Guy many thanks. i get it