# I'm trying to write a Tic-Tac-Toe game, but I run into this problem

Tags: python

As I just said, I'm writing a Tic-Tac-Toe game and an error ocurred that I'm still not able to fix. The Error itself involves the check of if the player has won. It doesn't show an explicit error message, but it just doesn't work how I wanted it to.

I first made a list of all the different winning possibillities. They look something like this:

```py
gridwintest = [[True, True, True,
                None, None, None,
                None, None, None],

               [None, None, None,
                True, True, True,
                None, None, None],
               
               [None, None, None,
                None, None, None,
                True, True, True],
               
               
               
               [True, None, None,
                True, None, None,
                True, None, None],
               
               [None, True, None,
                None, True, None,
                None, True, None],
               
               [None, None, True,
                None, None, True,
                None, None, True],
               
               
               
               [True, None, None,
                None, True, None,
                None, None, True],
               
               [None, None, True,
                None, True, None,
                True, None, None],
               ]
```

The function that handles them looks like this:

```py
def check_grid(grid,check):
    global gridwintest
    
    gridvl = []
    for item in grid:
        if item == check:
            gridvl.append(True)
        else:
            gridvl.append(None)
    correct = True
    for chkgrid in gridwintest:
        for i in range(len(chkgrid)-1):
            if not (chkgrid[i] == gridvl[i] or chkgrid[i] == None):
                correct = False
    return correct
```

The code that uses that function is:

```py
if check_grid(gridvl, invcurrmode):
        print("You won, "+currmode+"!")
        quit()
    elif check_grid(gridvl, currmode):
        print("Try again, "+currmode+".")
        quit()
```

But the return of the "check_grid" function is always false, even though if I logged the outputs of each line inside that function, it seems like it should actually be true.

Comment:  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: What do the values passed to `check_grid` as `grid` and `check` look like?

Comment: @match The 'grid' is the current grid and 'check' is the player that is being tested for a win

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify a bit by reducing

```
    correct = True
    for chkgrid in gridwintest:
        for i in range(len(chkgrid)-1):
            if not (chkgrid[i] == gridvl[i] or chkgrid[i] == None):
                correct = False
```

to

```
    for chkgrid in gridwintest:
        if chkgrid == gridvl:
                return True
    return False
```

Because Python allows [ordered list comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36420022/how-can-i-compare-two-ordered-lists-in-python) with `==`.

And that should solve your bug too. `not (chkgrid[i] == None)` will evaluate to `True` on any of the three `True` values in each winning grid.

Comment: The issue with that is if I don't EXCACTLY have 3 in a row (so [True,True,True,None,None,None,None,None,None]) it will count as nothing

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean. Could you clarify, or provide an example? Or, even better, verify the behavior by rolling that hypothesis into a test?